# Prairie Installation on Local Server Possible?

Tags: openid

Is it possible to install [Prairie](http://barnraiser.org/prairie) on the localhost? if yes then how Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to install it on the localhost.  You have to have a mail system though for it to accept the installation as well as mysql.  Basically, you need to run apache, then move the entire folder into the WWW folder.  Then access the prairie folder through the web browser.  Then everything is done on screen.  FYI you may need to comment out the email address check if you aren't using an email address with a fully qualified domain name like "example@gmail.com".  If you are using a mail system on the localhost you'll need to use an address like "example@localhost" which prairie will not accept.  So if you comment out the checking code it will work.